# Are we allowed to modify the order of the states within a Markov chain?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

For instance, if I were to switch the states such that the rows are in the order (0,1,2,3) but the columns are (1,2,0,3), can we still do the relevant analysis?

By observation, I see that the row sum is still equivalent to 1, so it does not seem to violate any MC requirements. This is because by changing the states around,  it can be easier to do certain forms of analysis.

Comment: Does $P^2$ still give you the two-step transition probabilities?

Comment: Such a modification totally changes properties of the MC. For example an absorbing state won't remain absorbing.